# Clone Git repository into iPhone

Tags: ios, git

I want to develop an iOS application that executes the `git clone` command to basically get a repository on the phone. After that the only command is `git fetch` so I will periodically update the files. After those 2 commands nothing more is required. just local parsing on the files.

My question is can I do that on iOS? I had a similar application working on ubuntu, and it was quite easy to do using 'git .....' commands

Answer (score 0):

you cant launch other apps / processes on ios so you cant call the git executable.

BUT there is libgit2 - a c static lib you can use in your ios app to work with git: see http://libgit2.github.com

there is a objC wrapper that makes it a breeze to use: see https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git on iOS via the [iSH app](https://ish.app/).

That is, you can install the app, install Git using `apk add git`, and then you are good to go.

This might not be directly useful to you, but I'm writing this here because this was the first hit on Google when I searched for "how to `git push`/`git pull` on iPhone"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).